# Would someone help me understand why this loop keeps repeating?

Tags: c++, loops

I wrote this code for class, everything is working fine except the full program loop, asking the user if they want to repeat the program. It doesn't seem to recognize the input characters to end the loop. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define REGULAR_HOURS_LIMIT 40.0    // hours at which overtime begins
#define OVERTIME_HOURS_LIMIT 20.0   // Maximum overtime hours
#define OVERTIME_RATE 1.5           // overtime rate
#define TAX_RATE 0.30               // tax rate (30%)
#define PARKING_RATE 10.00          // parking deduction
#define MAXIMUM_PAY_RATE 99.99      // Maximum employee pay

int main()
{
    string  first_name,     // employee's first name, input by user
            last_name,      // employee's last name, input by user
            full_name;      // employee's concatenated full name

    double  hours,          // number of hours worked, input by user
            regular_hours,  // number of regular hours
            overtime_hours, // number of overtime hours
            hourly_rate,    // hourly pay rate
            gross_pay,      // employee's gross pay
            tax,            // employee's tax amount
            deductions,     // monthly deductions
            net_pay;        // employee's net pay

    char    yesno;          // Prompt for new input 

    do
    {
// Input section

    cout << "Enter employee's first name: ";
    cin >> first_name;

    cout << "Enter employee's last name: ";
    cin >> last_name;

    cout << "Enter number of hours worked: ";
    cin >> hours;
        while (hours < 0 || hours > (REGULAR_HOURS_LIMIT + OVERTIME_HOURS_LIMIT))
        {
            cout << "Hours must be between 0 and 60" << endl;
            cout << "Enter number of hours worked: ";
            cin >> hours;
        }

    cout << "Enter hourly pay rate: $";
    cin >> hourly_rate;
        while (hourly_rate < 0 || hourly_rate > MAXIMUM_PAY_RATE)
        {
            cout << "Pay rate must be between 0.00 and 99.99" << endl;
            cout << "Enter hourly pay rate: $";
            cin >> hourly_rate;
        }

// Processing section

    full_name = last_name + ", " + first_name;

    if (hours <= REGULAR_HOURS_LIMIT) 
    {
        regular_hours = hours;
        overtime_hours = 0.0;
    }

    else 
    {
        regular_hours = REGULAR_HOURS_LIMIT;
        overtime_hours = hours - REGULAR_HOURS_LIMIT;
    }

    gross_pay = (regular_hours * hourly_rate) + (overtime_hours *

    hourly_rate * OVERTIME_RATE);

    tax = gross_pay * TAX_RATE;

    deductions = PARKING_RATE;

    net_pay = gross_pay - tax - deductions;

// Output section

cout << endl;
cout << "12345678901234567890##21.00##21.00##321.00##4321.00##321.00"
<< "##321.00##4321.00" << endl;
cout << " Reg. Ovt. Hourly Gross "
<< " Net " << endl;
cout << "Name Hours Hours Rate Pay Taxes "
<< " Deduct Pay " << endl;
cout << "==================== ===== ===== ====== ======= ======"
<< " ====== =======" << endl;
cout << left << setw(20) << full_name << " ";
cout << right << fixed << setprecision(2);
cout << setw(5) << regular_hours << " ";
cout << setw(5) << overtime_hours << " ";
cout << setw(6) << hourly_rate << " ";
cout << setw(7) << gross_pay << " ";
cout << setw(6) << tax << " ";
cout << setw(6) << deductions << " ";
cout << setw(7) << net_pay << endl << endl;


cout << "Process another employee (Y/N)?";
cin >> yesno;
    if (yesno == 'y' || 'Y' || 'n' || 'N')
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Please type 'Y' for yes or 'N' for no";
            cin >> yesno;
        }
        while (yesno != 'y' || 'Y' || 'n' || 'N');
    }
    }
    while (yesno == 'y' || 'Y');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change line

```
while (yesno == 'y' || 'Y');
```

to

```
while ((yesno == 'y') || (yesno == 'Y'));
```

In first case condition 'Y' is always true and you got infinite loop.
The same goes for lines

```
if (yesno == 'y' || 'Y' || 'n' || 'N')
...
while (yesno != 'y' || 'Y' || 'n' || 'N');
```

In this lines 'y', 'Y' and other chars implicity converted to bool 
according to the rule

> A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to true.

Comment: Did the trick. Thanks. I didn't realize I needed to restate the variable with each check, I'll keep it in mind in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
 while (yesno != 'y' || 'Y' || 'n' || 'N');
```

you must write yesno != 'y' && yesno != 'Y' && yesno != 'n' && yesno != 'N'

Comment: (It repeats because the value 'Y' is non-zero, therefore 'true' and therefore one of the || predicates is true and therefore the overall expression is always true)

Answer (score 0):

while (hourly_rate < 0 || hourly_rate > MAXIMUM_PAY_RATE)
why you loop this? its always true/false, use 
if (hourly_rate < 0 || hourly_rate > MAXIMUM_PAY_RATE) to check condition.
 whille is for looping